# Pegar um item de uma lista

Tags: python

Bom dia, eu venho tentando fazer um mini jogo, onde eu insiro as palavras na variável WORDS e o mesmo digita o nome de forma aleatória, até aqui Ok.
Mas eu queria mudar e não estou conseguindo fazer o que eu quero, pois não encontro uma forma de fazer o mesmo.(Comecei a estudar programação no fim de semana passada).
Segue o código:

```
import random

WORDS = ("palavra1", "palavra2", "palavra3")
word = random.choice(WORDS)
correct = word
champions = ""
while word:
    position = random.randrange(len(word))
    champions += word[position]
    word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]
print("")
print("A palavra é:", champions)
guess = input("Nome: ")
while guess != correct and guess != "":
    print("Essa não é a palavra")
    guess = input("A palavra é: ")
if guess == correct:
print("Você acertou\n")

input("\n\nPressione Enter para sair. Versão 1.0")
```

O que eu queria mudar, eu tentei fazer que o resultado da variável "word" puxasse uma dica de uma lista e inserir essa dica depois que a pessoa errar.

```
palavra1 = ["dica1","dica2","dica3"]
palavra2 = ["dica1","dica2","dica3"]
palavra3 = ["dica1","dica2","dica3"]
```

Exemplo:
    print("Essa não é a palavra")
    print("Dica:", dica1,".")

Imagino que ficou confuso, mas acho que da pra entender.

Comment: `WORDS` define uma lista de palavras que serão sorteadas. `word` é a palavra sorteada. `champions` é um anagrama de `word`. É exibido o valor `champions`, de forma que o usuário tente acertar a palavra correta, `correct`. O programa fica requisitando uma nova palavra até que o usuário acerte. Agora você deseja que uma dica seja exibida quando o usuário errar. Pergunta: Cada diva deve ser exibida apenas uma vez ou podem se repetir e sempre mostrar uma dica quando o usuário errar a palavra?

Comment: Sempre mostrar uma nova dica quando ele errar, coloquei uma repetição, mas não coloquei aqui no código do site, a pessoa vai ter cinco chances, se errar as cinco, perde.

Comment: E serão cinco dicas?

Comment: Sim, serão cinco dicas, coloquei somente três como exemplo, mas serão cinco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descreverei o programa por partes, pois acredito que alguns detalhes possam ser melhorados. Primeiro, vamos criar uma lista de palavras que farão parte do jogo de adivinhação. Para cada palavra, haverão cinco dicas.

```
WORDS = [
    ("palavra1", ["dica1", "dica2", "dica3", "dica4", "dica5"]),
    ("palavra2", ["dica1", "dica2", "dica3", "dica4", "dica5"]),
    ("palavra3", ["dica1", "dica2", "dica3", "dica4", "dica5"])
]
```

Para sortear uma palavra, junto com suas dicas, basta utilizar `random.choice`:

```
word = random.choice(WORDS)
```

Para criar um anagrama, isto é, embaralhar as letras da palavra, você pode converter a palavra para uma lista, utilizar o método `sort` e retornar para uma *string*:

```
anagram = list(word[0])
anagram.sort()
anagram = "".join(anagram)

print("Tente adivinhar:", anagram)
```

Para fazer a leitura das tentativas do usuário, considerando um máximo de 5 chances, basta utilizar um `for`:

```
# Cinco tentativas:
for i in range(5):

  # Lê a tentativa do usuário:
  guess = input("Tentativa #{}: ".format(i+1))

  # Varifica se o usuário acertou:
  if guess == word[0]: 

    # Sim, exime a mensagem e encerra o loop:
    print("Parabens! Você acertou.")
    break

  # Não, exibe uma dica:
  print("Dica:", word[1].pop(0))

else:
  # O usuário não acertou a palavra:
  print("Ihh, não foi dessa vez.")
```

Para exibir a dica, utilizei o método `pop`, retirando sempre a primeira dica da lista referente à palavra. Desta forma, as dicas serão dadas em ordem: dica 1, dica 2, dica 3, etc. Considerando que na primeira tentativa não haverá uma dica, para 5 chances são necessárias somente 4 dicas.

O programa completo ficaria:

```
import random

# Lista de palavras e as respectivas dicas:
WORDS = [
    ("palavra1", ["dica1", "dica2", "dica3", "dica4"]),
    ("palavra2", ["dica1", "dica2", "dica3", "dica4"]),
    ("palavra3", ["dica1", "dica2", "dica3", "dica4"])
]

# Sorteia uma palavra:
word = random.choice(WORDS)

# Gera o anagrama da palavra:
anagram = list(word[0])
anagram.sort()
anagram = "".join(anagram)

# Exibe o anagrama:
print("Tente adivinhar:", anagram)

# Cinco tentativas:
for i in range(5):

  # Lê a tentativa do usuário:
  guess = input("Tentativa #{}: ".format(i+1))

  # Varifica se o usuário acertou:
  if guess == word[0]: 

    # Sim, exime a mensagem e encerra o loop:
    print("Parabens! Você acertou.")
    break

  # Não, exibe uma dica:
  print("Dica:", word[1].pop(0))

else:
  # O usuário não acertou a palavra:
  print("Ihh, não foi dessa vez.")
```

> Veja funcionando no [Repli.it](https://repl.it/INEq) ou no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/zce9UI).

Comment: Obrigado Anderson, vou utilizar suas dicas. :)